# Java's Design by Contract Pattern

Tags: java

I have a question about this design pattern. The pre/post conditions are applicable only on the methods declared on an interface, or you can put them directly on the methods of a normal class? Or more exactly, it is correct TO to so? Nevertheless, I know that the pre/post conditions are only commentaries, but I want to know if it doesn't violate the DesignByContract structure.

Comment: Usually when it says "interface" in some patterns it's not necessarily an `interface`, it can be any "interface", even the public methods of a regular `class`. Whatever the "DesignByContract structure" is, it's not part of the language so you are only bound by some contract on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't support "design by contract" natively, like most other mainstream languages. Java interfaces are just a solution to avoid multiple inheritance,  they just declare what methods must a class have that implements that interface.

You could imitate design by contract with annotations (they can attach custom metadata to methods), but then we'd be talking about a framework built in Java and not about the features of the language.

Also something can't be a language feature and a design pattern at the same time. Design patterns are usually missing language features. (Or at least something more complicated than just using langauge features as intended.)